# How to explicitly define adding space in a string?

Tags: string, space

In an effort to make my code more readable I'd like to specifically say that I am adding a space to a string instead of just saying `+ " "`. As this could be easy confused with `+ ""`.

As a idea of what I'm looking for:

```
this.finalString = (string1 + //String.Space or Char.Space// +string2);
```

Is there a convention for this or is `" "` the proper way to do this?

Comment: What language? I don't think Eclipse has anything to do with this.  If you're using C/C++ you "could" assign a `string space = " "` and use that in your assignment, BUT that is very unusual.

Comment: " " is correct.  However, some languages might have additional constructs to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" " is the proper way to do this. :)

If you really need to be explicit, you can setup a constant to represent a single whitespace character.

If you don't like constants, you can create your own variables (depending on the language you're using):

```
String space = " ";
String return = Environment.NewLine;
String example = space + "word" + return + "anotherword";
```

Comment: I thought of that but your but I agree that would be overkill. And not all that much better due to the initialization still being (String whatever = " ")

Answer (score 1):

To be honest anyone who is experienced in any language isn't going to confuse these two statements

```
this.finalString = (string1 + "" +string2);  // No one does this, unless it's a typo
```

and

```
this.finalString = (string1 + " " +string2);
```